# Office 365 Email SPF

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, office365connectors

We have an application that collects donations on behalf of various clients.  Once the donation is processed, we then send a welcome email.  The welcome email originates from the clients own domain.  We either use Exchange WebService to connect and send the email or set up the domain on a local exchange server and then have the client config their SPF record to allow this.

Unfortunately we no longer have the local exchange server, having migrated to Office 365 and connecting to client accounts via Exchange WebServices.

A new client does not want to use Exchange WebServices and are also using Office 365.

My question is, how can I use SPF to send the welcome email from our Office 365 subscription? I thought I would have been able to add the domain as an accept domain (internal relay), however this doesn't seem possible?

Answer (score 0):

Domain at the same time can only be added to one tenant, so you can't add it as accepted domain to your tenant for sure.

One way would be to send it via their tenant. (then they would have to create you an account in their tenant)

Other one (requires IP from which you are sending to be in their SPF record), if you agree with customer that he will add your IP address to their SPF - you can send email manually and "spoof" the sender address to look like it's from their organization. (if anyone replies to it - you can ask for customer to create "shared mailbox" with same email address or create distribution group with you inside of it for getting the replies) here are the steps, and you can script them - http://www.wikihow.com/Forge-Email

Comment: HaRa, thanks for your reply - in the end I used SendGrid to send the welcome emails - also give us access to stats